# Correct to place an #undef directive in C++ headers/implementation files

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor

I am writing a class (separated in header file `myClass.h` and implementation file `myClass.cpp`) which I want to use with both standard C++ and the Qt framework. Since the differences in the code are very small (and I wanted to try it out once), I decided to `#define USINGQT 1` in order to toggle the small sections of code via

```
#if USINGQT==1
    //Qt code
#else
    //standard code
#endif
```

Now I came to the conclusion that it'd be convenient to use `QString`s throughout the whole class instead of `std::string`s when "activating" the `USINGQT` switch. However, the method above would render the code extremely messy. My solution (in the header file):

```
#if USINGQT==1
    #include <QString>
    #define string QString
#else
    #include <string>
    #define string std::string
#endif
```

**Now to the question:**

Consider the files to look like

```
---myclass.h-------------------------
#ifndef MYCLASS_H
#define MYCLASS_H

#define USINGQT 1  //1=on, else off
#if USINGQT==1
    #include <QString>
    #define string QString
#else
    #include <string>
    #define string std::string
#endif

namespace mySpace {

class MyClass {
    string qtOrStd;
    string foo();
    //etc...
};

} //namespace
#endif //MYCLASS_H
-------------------------------------

---myclass.cpp-----------------------
#include "myclass.h"
using namespace mySpace;

//implementations
string MyClass::foo()   //string symbol occurs, as does the USINGQT
-------------------------------------
```

1. Where is the correct place to `#undef` the `string` and `USINGQT` symbols? At the end of the header file (which would then require a redefinition and "undefinition" in the implementation file as well) or just at the end of the implementation file?
2. I should capitalize the `string` macro as well, shouldn't I...? >.>
3. If I put the macro definitions *inside* the namespace I receive approx. 800 error messages with entries like "no member of mySpace::std" among others. Can you say something about that without further information? Otherwise it compiles just fine.

---

EDIT: I may should have told you that I want the macros to only apply to this specific header AND its implementation file. Despite the fact that I will of course go for the `typedef`s - in the macro case, I'd guess, I should place the `#undef` at the end of the implementation file. Because the macros won't be redefined because of the include guards.

Comment: Avoid use `string` for your #define, you have a conflict with std::string after `#using namespace mySpace`

Comment: Would mean to 2): Yes, use `STRING` for instance... But how is there a conflict? Because every `string` occurrence would be replaced properly...? While the macro is in effect I would *only* use `string` and no specific `std::string` or `QString`...

Comment: Your approach looks quite ugly in general. Why don't you use templates to make your class working with any std-like string implementation?  
`template<class StringImpl> class MyClass {
    StringImpl qtOrStd;
    StringImpl foo();
    //etc...
};`

Comment: Because 1) I want to learn about the usage of preprocessor directives and their rules and 2) the string-thing is just a minor detail for convenience - the real differences lie in other parts of the code which are not of interest here (and can not be come by with templates conveniently). 3) I want to restrict dependencies. No Qt --> no Qt includes.

Comment: Regarding 3) from your comment, you wouldn't need to include any string file when you use templates... The user of your class does that, and then instantiates the class with the concrete string implementation. But of course, I can't know how complex your use case is actually.

Comment: I definitely see your point, and if it was just about the strings, then of course, the template option would be the one to go. But one of the functions uses the `QFile` class for instance, etc, etc... *This* is just for learning about preprocessor directives and for not having to convert to standard strings all the time when actually using Qt. ^^

Comment: `string` doesn't have to be a macro (macros are evil). It can be a simple type alias: `using string = QString;` and `using std::string;`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not see any reason to `#undef` the macro. Surely you want *all* your code to be compiled with *one* state of that macro? Then you will not need to `#undef` it.

However, I also strongly suggest you to use `typedef` for your `string` definition. This will anyway be clearer, you will not think about capitalizing it, and you can even put it into your namespace. Use `::` if you need to access global namespace:

```
#define USINGQT
#ifdef USINGQT
    #include <QString>
#else
    #include <string>
#endif

namespace mySpace {
    #ifdef USINGQT
    typedef ::QString string;
    #else
    typedef ::std::string string;
    #endif
}
```

Also note (as shown above) that if you need just a *boolean* value for macro, then you don't need to make it `1` or `0`, just use `#ifdef`/`#ifndef`.

After this, in your `.cpp`, just use `mySpace::string` and never bother about macroses.

Comment: Please see my question edit for why I think I need `#undef`. Ah, I see, do I understand right that the additional `::` avoid a "mySpace::QString not defined" error?

Comment: @LCsa, yes, `::` (or similar code) should make the compiler to look for `QString` in the global namespace. And for your edit, I'd suggest you undefine at end of header (so that other files `#include`ing your header are not polluted; or just choose some `define` name that you will not use anywhere else, and then you do not need to `#undef`.

Comment: Yep, the `typedef` should cover the problem with the `#undef`ing of `string`. However, *if* I undefine `USINGQT` in the header, I would have to temporarily re-introduce it in the implementation file...

Comment: @LCsa, it's very strange that you need this QT macro for one file only. What is harm to have it for the whole project?

Comment: Haha, I know it must look very strange! This is really rather a technical question than a design question (although I really appreciate the typedef-hint - I don't know why I didn't use them right away). But a short explanation to stop you from wondering: I have one project containing a couple of very small utility classes which have often nothing to do with each other. I don't want all them in different projects, I want them next to each other, when working on them. When *using* one of them, I just copy the header and cpp file. PLUS, learning for the what-if-case. ;-)

Answer (score 5):

1. Firstly you do not need to toggle `USINGQT` by making it equal to 1 you can simply `#define USINGQT` and then use `#ifdef USINGQT` for your if statement.
2. In terms of your ability to toggle which string library you use I would suggest using a typedef alongside a pre-processor if statement. This would avoid any namespace issues. An example of this is shown below.

// -------------- Some config file -------------=

```
#define USINGQT

// -------------- MyClass.h --------------------=
// Header guard
#ifndef MyClass
#define MyClass 

// Conditional Header types
#ifdef USINGQT
// QT OPTION
typedef QString my_string;

#else
//  Not QT
typedef std::string my_string;
#endif

class MyClass {
public:
    my_string some_string;

    MyClass()
    {
        my_string = "hello world";
    }
};
#endif
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't *have* to `#undef` macros unless another file tries to re-define it. You can't `#undef` a macro *before* you're done using it and therefore, if you `#define` a macro in a header and want to use it in files that include the header, then you cannot `#undef` it in that header.

> 1) Where is the correct place to #undef the string and USINGQT symbols? At the end of the header file ...

*Only* if you use it in that header... but you apparently do use it a file that includes the header, so *no*.

> or just at the end of the implementation file?

Undefining a macro at the end of an implementation file is pointless, because there will be no code after the end of the file to which the macro applies anymore. Just let it stay defined.

> 2) I should capitalize the string macro as well, shoudln't I...? >.>

You don't have to capitalize macros, but it's a convention. That said, defining a macro by the same name as a standard class is just asking for trouble. You should use a `typedef` instead of a macro here in order to get meaningful error messages in case of name conflicts. And use another name like `string_t` or define the `typedef` in a namespace.

> 3) If I put the macro definitions inside the namespace I receive approx. 800 error messages

The errors don't come from defining the macros inside a namespace. The errors come from using the macros as-if they were part of the namespace. For example, if you say:

```
namespace mySpace {
#define string std::string
}
mySpace::string s;
```

then the `string` will be replaced with `std::string` and the typename becomes `mySpace::std::string`. Since you haven't defined a `std` namespace inside `mySpace`, this is wrong. What you need to understand is that namespaces don't have any effect on preprocessor macros. Which makes it harder to avoid name conflicts which is one reason why you usually want to avoid pre-processor macros.

If the `USINGQT` macro applies to *all* of your code such that it must be same for all files, you may want to not define it in a header at all, but instead pass it as an argument to the compiler. That way you can easily compile with different values without changing a file.

---

About your edit:

Even if you want the macro to be defined differently in another file, then undefining it at the end of the implementation has no effect, because the implementation file won't be included by the files that include the header. You should avoid a situation where you need multiple, *different* definitions (or lack of definitions) of macros, but if you're in such a situation, then yes, your only solution is to define it separately in each file that needs it and then undefine at the end of any header that needs it. But you're not in a such situation because you can use a type alias instead.

Comment: I may should have told you that there are not just those two files in the project! But I want the macros to only apply to this specific header AND its implementation file. But then I want to undefine at least the `string` in order to avoid conflicts in other classes that use for instance `std::string`. My guess was "end of implementation", because it will be compiled once and every other occurrence of #include"myclass.h" would not define the macros anymore due to the include guards... (However, this shows already that `string` is a poorly chosen name)

Comment: @LCsa there's now an addendum in my answer regarding your edit.